# Display specific PHP array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Right now all the columns from the MySQL result are converted to JSON and printed out on the screen. I would like to print only two column `$row['name']` and `$row['gender']` to the screen. Any ideas guys

```
include('connect-db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patientvaccinedetail")


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {

print_r(json_encode($row));}
```

Comment: You are using mysql_* functions which are now deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the future.So you need to start using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for getting all from the table and display only two values....

```
include('connect-db.php');    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patientvaccinedetail") //getting all the fields    

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
    $data = array('name' => $row['name'] , 'gender' => $row['gender']); //get the two values into one array

print_r(json_encode($data)); //printing the name and gender
}
```

If you want to get only that two fields here is another query...

```
include('connect-db.php');    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,gender FROM patientvaccinedetail") //getting two the fields    

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {     

print_r(json_encode($row)); //printing the name and gender
}
```

Comment: May i ask one more thing, for the message sent it's Chinese, so right now it cant display correctly but some random character i.e.B\u578b\u809d\u708e\u75ab\

Comment: in the heading, i've set  to utf-8

Comment: Open new question Because we need explanation @tam

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,gender FROM patientvaccinedetail")
```

Comment: Yes, just select those columns you need. Don't use * which is "give me everything just in case..." AND Can we please LOOSE the mysql and use mysqli or pdo or something...

Comment: The first is i want all the column for the display, but i just want two column to covert to JSON format to send to the SMS API

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data but you have to print only name & gender then ..Create one separate array & allocate name & gender...

```
$data_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {
 array_push($data_array,array("name"=>$row['name'],"gender"=>$row['gender']);
}
print_r(json_encode($data_array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
include('connect-db.php');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,gender FROM patientvaccinedetail")


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)) {

print_r(json_encode($row));}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)